# How do I find the credentials for PostgreSQL deployed via a charm?

Tags: juju

I have deployed the postgresql charm (the recommended one) and tweaked its configuration but now I would like to know the parameters to connect to it like username, password... in the readme there is a part that says: 'the postgresql service provides' and then a list with 'host' 'database' 'user' 'password'... How can I access this so I can configure another service to connect to it manually?

I have deployed the python-django charm and created a relationship with postgres thinking it would autoconfigure the django settings file to connect to postgres and I could inspect it to see the parameters. But then when I ssh into the machine where python-django runs and I do `find / -name 'settings.py'` it returns only some template settings files with an empty db config

Comment: I have deployed the python-django charm and created a relationship with postgres thinking it would autoconfigure the django settings file to connect to postgres and I could inspect it to see the parameters. But then when I ssh into the machine where python-django runs and I do `find / -name 'settings.py'` it returns only some template settings files with an empty db config.

Comment: I have found where it is kept: /srv/python_django/juju_settings/20-engine-pgsql.py All the django db settings are there.

Answer (score 1):

All the options are kept at:

```
/srv/python_django/juju_settings/20-engine-pgsql.py
```